# Can I combine 2 eloquent where query into single query?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, where-clause

I have 2 queries that are almost similar to $other_document and $author_document, is it possible to combine the 2 queries into one query?

```
$document = Document::findOrFail($id);
$other_document = Document::forExplore()->latest()->paginate(4);
$author_document = Document::where('user_id', $document->user_id)->forExplore()->latest()->paginate(4);

return view('document.show', compact('document','other_document','author_document'));
```

For now, I can only separate them into two variable then merge two variable into single variable. what I want is that 2 query can I simplify into single query then assign into single variable.

Comment: The results of $author_document should be a subset of the results of $other_document. Can't you get everything from $other_document? Or do you specifically need 4 from each?

Answer (score 0):

you can combine the two queries into a single query using the **union** method.

```
$documents = Document::forExplore()
                 ->latest()
                 ->where('user_id', $document->user_id)
                 ->union(Document::forExplore()->latest())
                 ->paginate(4);
return view('document.show', compact('document', 'documents'));
```

Note: The union method is only supported in Laravel 8.0 or higher. If you are using an earlier version of Laravel, you can use the DB::table method to perform a union of two queries.